# how cai i solve this problem of my code of getting my hand position using MRTK?

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, hololens, mrtk

this is a code with MRTK to continuously get the position of my hand with Hololens 1. but it doesn't work because trygetposition is not recognized. how can i solve this problem ?

```
using System.Collections;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using UnityEngine;  
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit;  
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;  
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities;  
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class HandPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
  
    public Text myText;
  
  
    public void OnSourceDetected(SourceStateEventData eventData)
    {

        var hand = eventData.InputSource as IMixedRealitySourceStateHandler;
        Vector3 handDetectedPosition;
        if (hand != null)
            {
            hand.TryGetPosition(eventData.SourceId, out handDetectedPosition);
            
                   myText.text = (handDetectedPosition*1000).ToString();
       } 
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Hololens 1 can't track your hand position. It only recognizes the air tap gesture, and uses your gaze pointer to select. You need a Hololens 2 if you want to track your hands.

Answer (score 1):

Hand tracking is the newest feature of HoloLens2, it is not available on HoloLens (1st gen), so you cannot obtain hand position data from HoloLens1. We recommend that you modify the [interaction model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/interaction-fundamentals) of your app to use head gaze instead of hand tracking as an input. More information please see:[Gaze and commit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/gaze-and-commit)

Comment: Thank you very much for the information!!